# Finding all $\alpha$ such that a matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, inner-products

I have

$A = $
$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    2 & \alpha & -1 \\
    \alpha & 2 & 1 \\
    -1 & 1 & 4
  \end{array}\right]
$

and I want to find all $\alpha$ such that $A$ is positive definite.

I tried

$ x^tAx = $
$
  \left[\begin{array}{r}
    x & y & z
  \end{array}\right]
$
$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    2 & \alpha & -1 \\
    \alpha & 2 & 1 \\
    -1 & 1 & 4
  \end{array}\right]
$
$
  \left[\begin{array}{r}
    x \\
    y \\
    z 
  \end{array}\right]
$

$=$
$
  \left[\begin{array}{r}
    2x + \alpha y - z & \alpha x + 2y + z & -x + y + 4z
  \end{array}\right]
$
$
  \left[\begin{array}{r}
    x \\
    y \\
    z 
  \end{array}\right]
$

$= 2x^2 + \alpha xy - xz + \alpha xy + 2y^2 + yz - xz + yz + 4z^2$

$= 2 \alpha xy + 2x^2 + 2y^2 - 2xz + 2yz + 4z^2$

and I wanted to solve the inequality $2 \alpha xy + 2x^2 + 2y^2 - 2xz + 2yz + 4z^2 > 0$ for $\alpha$, but I wasn't sure what to do next.

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: I'd use determinants here instead of quadratic forms like this. Specifically, look at the its leading principal minors: the determinants of 2 (trivial), $\begin{bmatrix}2&\alpha\\\alpha&2\end{bmatrix}$, and the full matrix. All three must be positive.

Comment: Do you want an example of $\alpha$ for which the matrix is positive definite or all the possible $\alpha$?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane I'm looking for an interval where $A$ is positive definite.

Comment: user38034's hint will lead you to what you want, if you know how to determine where a quadratic function is positive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

A hermitian matrix is positive definite $\Leftrightarrow$ all leading principal minors are positive.

So $\left|\begin{array}{r}
    2
  \end{array}\right|$, $\left|\begin{array}{rr}
    2 & \alpha \\
    \alpha & 2
  \end{array}\right|$ and  $\left|\begin{array}{rrr}
    2 & \alpha & -1 \\
    \alpha & 2 & 1 \\
    -1 & 1 & 4
  \end{array}\right|$ have to be positive.

This gives us 
$$\begin{align}&\text{I:}\quad 2>0\\
&\text{II:}\quad 4-\alpha^2>0\\
&\text{III:}\quad -4\alpha^2 - 2\alpha +12>0
\end{align}
$$
Try to solve this!

Comment: Great hint, +1. Minor details: a "hermitian" matrix is positive definite if and only if all of the "leading" principal minors are positive (you don't need all the principal minors, like you don't need $4$, for instance, as you perfectly did in your answer). This is called [Sylvester's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_criterion).

Comment: Thanks, edited the word "leading"

Comment: You're welcome. You should add hermitian too. It is false otherwise.

Comment: How did you get inequality III?

Comment: @user13985 Determinant of the third matrix > 0.

Answer (score 4):

The matrix is positive definite if and only if their eigenvalues are positive, so we calculate the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(x)=\det(xI-A)$ and we solve for $x$ and we find:
$$\lambda_1=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\alpha+12}-\frac{1}{2}\alpha+3,\quad\lambda_2=3-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\alpha+12}- \frac{1}{2}\alpha,\quad \lambda_3=\alpha+2$$
hence we should find the $\alpha$ for which $\lambda_i>0, i=1,2,3$.

Comment: I suspect that if you eliminate the square root in either $\lambda_1>0$ or $\lambda_2>0$ you will obtain a quadratic form similar to the determinant above.